# Cannot convert value of type '[String : Int]' to type 'Dictionary<_, _>' in coercion

Tags: swift3

I just converted my code to swift3 and got this error.

`act.performAction(["status":VSM.ble_RX_DATA_PARSE_ERROR.rawValue] as Dictionary)`

Comment: I guess performAction expects `NSDictionary`, and `Dictionary` is `Swift` `generic` type.

Comment: ok. understood. so i don't need to specify the generic type now?

Comment: if you will use `Dictionary` you will have to, if you will use `NSDictionary` — you won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add `as Dictionary` here. This probably used to be `as NSDictionary` and was mechanically modified, but you shouldn't need that now. (Even if you did, you'd need to add the `NS` back in that case.)

Comment: so i don't need to specify the generic type now?

Comment: i used NSMutableDictionary and it works now. You were right, the converted mechanically modified it